# Edits not being saved for custom fields on relationships

Tags: custom-fields, relationships

When editing a relationship with custom fields and changing a value, the value does not get saved.

When creating a new relationship however, values entered into the custom field at that point are saved.

I have tested it with all extensions disabled.

I have created a new set of custom fields on a different relationship type and this also has the problem.

We are running version  4.7.17 and this was a problem in the previous version too.

Comment: Have you confirmed on a demo site, eg dmaster.demo.civicrm.org?

Comment: seems to be an issue as it also replicates on demo. Should be filed on JIRA. https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa

Comment: Thanks, have done so now https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in said version, but is now fixed.